# Vertical page swipe feature in tizen wearable(only using TAU)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I couldnt find any default animation features supported by tizen other than **data-transition="slideup"** for **anchor tag or popups**. Is it that I didnt explore well or tizen(using TAU) gives limited support to animation for some reasons like performance? Can we use something like page swiper in wearable?

Comment: Did you find Horizontal swipe ?

Comment: No. While reading tau.js the examples they gave are for slide up. That itself is there only for popups and anchor tags. And i'm interested in vertical animation. So posted like that. Hope u know the answer and can guide me.

Comment: So, want to develop a vertical slide ?

Comment: yes. can you help me with that? Whether TAU supports this functionality?

Comment: Let me check first....

Comment: Sure. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge Tizen don't have any Vertical Swipe control till now. You can find Horizontal swipe from online sample,

**New Project>Online Sample> [TAUUIComponents](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/sample/web/UI/TAU_UI_Components)**

From this app goto **Controls>Page Indicator** for horizontal swipe.

If you want to use vertical swipe, i think you have to developed by your own. You can use TAU for this or you can you external library like JQuery.

I will suggest to use [dragend JS](http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/) for this purpose. You can get the source code for this from [here](https://github.com/Stereobit/dragend).

-Thanks

Comment: I already tried dragend but with my UI designed in TAU the animation is going weird. Thats why I asked you if something is possible with TAU itself. Anyways thanks a lot. I'll try to fix that.