# TAU: How do we use the PageIndicator for Wearable Devices

Tags: html, css, swipe, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am trying the [Page Indicator](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Wearable_UIComponents/wearable_pageindicator.htm) in Tizen Wearable Application for Gear S3 Frontier. When I use the code pasted there, **It works fine for text only**. E.g. when I try to add controls on each section (being shown as page on the screen) It doesn't work. Even if I set a background image the whole design gets scattered. I've tried some approaches, including the answer given on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641999/vertical-page-swipe-feature-in-tizen-wearableonly-using-tau)

**My Output:**

[image] [image]

**HTML Code:**

#### Page1 of 2

#### Page2 of 2

**CSS:**

```
.ui-content section {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 /*global tau */
(function() {

var page = document.getElementById("taskListPage"),
    changer = document.getElementById("hsectionchanger"),
    sections = document.querySelectorAll("section"),
    sectionChanger,
    elPageIndicator = document.getElementById("pageIndicator"),
    pageIndicator,
    pageIndicatorHandler;

/**
 * pagebeforeshow event handler
 * Do preparatory works and adds event listeners
 */
page.addEventListener( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    // make PageIndicator
    pageIndicator =  tau.widget.PageIndicator(elPageIndicator, { numberOfPages: sections.length });
    pageIndicator.setActive(0);
    // make SectionChanger object
    sectionChanger = new tau.widget.SectionChanger(changer, {
        circular: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        useBouncingEffect: true
    });
});

/**
 * pagehide event handler
 * Destroys and removes event listeners
 */
page.addEventListener( "pagehide", function() {
    // release object
    sectionChanger.destroy();
    pageIndicator.destroy();
});

/**
 * sectionchange event handler
 */
pageIndicatorHandler = function (e) {
    pageIndicator.setActive(e.detail.active);
};

changer.addEventListener("sectionchange", pageIndicatorHandler, false);

}());
```

I am **facing an error** as well:
`file:///lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js (20) :[tau][10/24/2019, 1:28:31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code is not attached. Basing on the screens I assume that your application has two sections. The SectionChanger widget with "circular" option can be build only with apps that contain at least 3 sections, hence the error in console.
Please change the circular option for section changer to false:

```
page.addEventListener( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    // make PageIndicator
    pageIndicator =  tau.widget.PageIndicator(elPageIndicator, { numberOfPages: sections.length });
    pageIndicator.setActive(0);
    // make SectionChanger object
    sectionChanger = new tau.widget.SectionChanger(changer, {
        circular: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        useBouncingEffect: true
    });
});
```

into:

```
page.addEventListener( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
    // make PageIndicator
    pageIndicator =  tau.widget.PageIndicator(elPageIndicator, { numberOfPages: sections.length });
    pageIndicator.setActive(0);
    // make SectionChanger object
    sectionChanger = new tau.widget.SectionChanger(changer, {
        circular: false,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        useBouncingEffect: true
    });
});
```

This option is responsible for switching between sections mode. If it's set to true user can move from first section to the last one and vice versa.